# Iterate through JSON Array to produce a Java list

Tags: java, arrays, json, list

I have a JSON array list that looks like this:

```
[{"dog":1,"cat":2},{"dog":3,"cat":4}]
```

and I want to convert it to a list in Java that looks like:

```
[12, 34]
```

I've thought about using `mapper.readValue` but I think that will still have the `"dog"` and `"cat"` in the final list.

What is a easy way to extract the values and put them in a list form?

Comment: You have (after running through just about any JSON parser) a List of Map objects.  Read the spec pages for List and Map and figure out how to do what you want.  It's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will have to iterate the array one object at a time and right some logic to get object.

> 1. get {"dog":1,"cat":2},create temp variable
> 2. get "dog":1 add 1 to temp
> 3. get "cat":2 add 2 to temp
> 4. put temp in list.

I dont see any api to do this